# Method src does not exist error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I was just trying to create a link in laravel like so:

```
   <li><a href="products/productspg">products</a></li>
```

I have a products controller with the following method in it:

```
public function getProductpg() {
    return View::make('store.products')
        ->with('products' , Product::take(4)->orderBy('created_at' , 'DESC')->get());
}
```

Also i have a `products` view under the store folder, i.e. `products.blade.php`,

now when i click on the link on the index page on I.E. the below link:

```
<li><a href="products/productspg">products</a></li>
```

I expect the below view to open:

`products.blade.php` , instead i get the following error :

[image: Error]

Now why am i getting this error , when i try to load even the index page of my app, this is not working , Why ?

**EDIT**:: turns out one of the stack traces shows the following:

```
<?php echo HTML::src('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'); ?>
```

And that line was present in my `main.blade.php` file , but even after deleting that , i am still getting the same error , is it an error with caching ?

Comment: If you look at the contents of `main.blade.php` you may find out.

Comment: The error message shows the view, please post the view's code which calls `src()` (or just remove the call to a non existing function)

Comment: @michael where do i find the code that calls src() ?

Comment: @sjagr well , i did't edit any code in main.blade.php and it was working fine , just after i added the above code am i getting this error !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Post the contents! I'm sure it looks fine to you but we may notice something you haven't.

Answer (score 1):

What is in your routes.php?
It seems that your link to products/productspg is calling a src method via routes.php which either not exist or you defined it with post::